# Как бы вы расставили запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

*Но почему и всегда ли, для всякого ли конфликта верны эти слова?*

Comment: К чему относится "почему"? Почему...верны эти слова? Так?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его как принятый (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Знаки препинания расставлены верно, перед "И"нет запятой, потому что это однородные обстоятельства, "И" не повторяется.

Если сочтёте уточнением "для всякого ли конфликта", возможно поставить запятую, ведь присутствует сужение смысла, но возможно  объяснение и как однородных членов, тогда запятой нет. Нужен весь контекст, чтобы решить этот вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, это из сочинения ученика, много стояло лишних запятых.

Answer (score 1):

Фраза очень косноязычная получилась, поэтому вопрос о пунктуации остается открытым. Как верно было сказано, "почему очень трудно связать с остальной частью предложения. Если так: "Почему [...] верны эти слова?"*, то фраза более или менее осмыслена, но слишком оторвано за счет развернутого вопроса *"для всякого ли конфликта"*?

Но скорее всего "Почему?" здесь самостоятельные вопрос. И, если не править саму фразу, то надо пунктуационно разбить её на две:

***Но почему? И всегда ли, для всякого ли конфликта верны эти слова?***

Или уже менять саму фразу, но без контекста это сделать затруднительно.

В сочинении, наверное, надо сделать замечание за стиль, а пунктуацию за ошибку не считать.

Answer (score 0):

Но почему и всегда ли, **для всякого ли конфликта,** верны эти слова?

Здесь возможно обособление, так как обстоятельство "для всякого конфликта" сужает значение обстоятельства  "всегда".